# Load custom configuration section from relative path locations

Tags: c#, configuration, config, app-config, configuration-files

I would like to load the configuration for a Custom Configuration Section from a path outside of the execution directory.

I realize the difference between "file" and "configSource" attributes.

Therefore, for a Custom Config Section, is there a way to implement an attribute like "file" and load the configuration from a relative path?